# Upload an entire folder's files with jquery.MultiFile.js instead of having to select each file individually

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, c#-3.0, file-upload

I have jquery multi-file working as shown in [link text](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317). However, what I really need is to be able to select a folder, then every file contained in the selected folder to be listed, at which the user could then remove any unwanted files before hitting 'upload.'

Has anyone done this with jquery multi-file upload? Would it be difficult to modify multi-file.js to make it do this? Are there any other open-source possibilities? I would love to use the ASP.NET FileUpload control without any javascript but it seems rather limited [I have virtually no javascript knowledge...yet].

Any insights, tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This widget still uses HTML's `<input type=file>` capabilities that is extremely simple and non-customizable. That's why you won't be able to change existing script to be able of selecting multiple files inside Open File dialog.

For selecting multiple files at once you're going to have to use Flash. The good news is, they normally come with upload progress bar as well.

Try [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) plugin script instead.